# Valgrind Conditional jump or move depends of unitialized value(s) when using chained call of variadic functions

Tags: c++, c, valgrind, variadic-functions, variadic

Main data is three double defined in the main. A variadic function, *wrapperVariadic*, take them and return true iff sum of them is strictly positiv. Given numbers are all small and positiv, so the result must be true.
*wrapperVariadic* call summerVariadic for get sum of all numbers.
*summerVariadic* put each number in a double *std::vector*, then call *summerNonVariadic* for compute sum of all numbers contained in the vector.

Problem : va_args in *summerVariadic* are always zero. When use *valgrind* on final executable, it detects "*Conditional jump or move depends of unitialized value(s)*" in main. According to *--track-origin=yes* option, origin of this is *Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation*.

The three functions used :

```
// simple vector summer
float summerNonVariadic(const std::vector<double> values) {
        float sum = 0.;
        for(unsigned int summed = 0; summed < values.size(); summed++) {
                sum += values[summed];
        }
        return sum; 
}



// put the n doubles in a vector, and call summerNonVariadic.
float summerVariadic(const unsigned int n, ...) {
        std::vector<double> values;
        va_list args;
        va_start(args, n); 

        for(unsigned int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                values.push_back(va_arg(args, double));
                //printf("AIG:%f\n", values.back());
                // printf call show that pushed values are always equal to zero,
                // and generates lots of "Conditional jump" valgrind error
        }

        va_end(args);
        return summerNonVariadic(values); 
}



// the wrapper
bool wrapperVariadic(const unsigned int n, ...) {
        va_list args;
        va_start(args, n); 
        float summer_said = summerVariadic(n, args);
        va_end(args);
        return summer_said > 0; 
}
```

A macro for runtime following:

```
#define LOGOK fprintf(stderr,"OK:%s:%u\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
```

The main function, in *main.cpp* :

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
        double a = 4.2, b = 5.1, c = 0.3;
        bool bool_res = wrapperVariadic(3, a, b, c);
        LOGOK // line 125
        if(bool_res) {
                LOGOK // line 127, never reached
        }
        LOGOK // line 129

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Call valgrind:

```
valgrind --leak-check=full --track-origins=yes  ./a.out
```

Final Output:

```
==8624== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==8624== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==8624== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==8624== Command: ./a.out
==8624== 
OK:main.cpp:125
==8624== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==8624==    at 0x40B9AD: main (main.cpp:126)
==8624== 
OK:main.cpp:129
==8624== 
==8624== HEAP SUMMARY:
==8624==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8624==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 4 frees, 80 bytes allocated
==8624== 
==8624== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==8624== 
==8624== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==8624== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==8624== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 4)
```

We can see that final value is false, because of bad reading of double values of the vector in *summerNonVariadic*.

Replace line 124 in main by *double bool_res = summerVariadic(3, a, b, c);* remove all error and generate expected result. (OK:main.cpp:127)

What is the problem with this chained variadic function call ?

versions:

```
gcc version 4.7.2 (Debian 4.7.2-5)
```

Comment: I don't see any line numbers in the valgrind output, are you compiling with `-g` ? if so, what line is the jump occurring on?

Comment: @RyanHaining There is no line showed in valgrind output. The jump occurying at line 126 of main, at `if(bool_res) {`. bool_res appear as an unitialized value. I will update post with using of `-g` flag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you use `summerVariadic(n, args);`, you have to provide `float summerVariadic(const unsigned int n, va_list args)`.

Since C++11, you may use variadic template instead:

```
template<typename ... Ts>
float summerVariadic(Ts... args) {
    return summerNonVariadic({args...}); 
}
```

Comment: Perfect solution ! But in pure C code, it first solution ugly ? summerVariadic define as `float summerVariadic(const unsigned int n, va_list args)` can't be used as a  normal variadic function ?

Comment: @aluriak: In pure C, you don't have `std::vector`. Instead of ellipsis, a float array may be an alternative. Almost each ellipsis functions should have (and call) its equivalent function with `va_list`, so you can call both, with `va_list` or with ellipsis.